# Comparison between 2D and 3D Affine transforms

Tags: cgal, affinetransform

Is it expected that the following test should fail?

The test compares results of a 2D and a 3D AffineTransformation. Both are constructed to have unit scaling and zero offsets in the y and z direction, but to have non-zero and non-unity scaling and offset in the x direction. All other off-diagonal elements are zero. It is my belief that these transformations are identical in the x and y directions, and hence should produce identical results.

Furthermore I have found that the test passes if I use this Kernel:

```
using K = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel;
```

Is it to be expected that the test passes if I use this Kernel? Should the test fail with either kernel or pass with either kernel?

```
TEST(TransformerTest, testCGALAffine) {
using K = CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel;
using Float = typename K::FT;
using Transformation_2 = K::Aff_transformation_2;
using Transformation_3 = K::Aff_transformation_3;
using Point_2 = typename K::Point_2;
using Point_3 = typename K::Point_3;

double lowerCorner(17.005142946538115);
double upperCorner(91.940521484752139);
int resolution = 48;
double tmpScaleX((upperCorner - lowerCorner) / resolution);
Float scaleX(tmpScaleX);
Float zero(0);
Float unit(1);

// create a 2D voxel to world transform
Transformation_2 transformV2W_2(scaleX, zero, Float(lowerCorner),
                                zero, unit, zero,
                                unit);
// create it's inverse: a 2D world to voxel transform
auto transformW2V_2 = transformV2W_2.inverse();

// create a 3D voxel to world transform
Transformation_3 transformV2W_3(scaleX, zero, zero, Float(lowerCorner),
                                zero, unit, zero, zero,
                                zero, zero, unit, zero,
                                unit);
// create it's inverse: a 3D world to voxel transform
auto transformW2V_3 = transformV2W_3.inverse();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
        EXPECT_EQ(transformV2W_2.cartesian(i, j), transformV2W_3.cartesian(i, j)) << i << ", " << j;
        EXPECT_EQ(transformW2V_2.cartesian(i, j), transformW2V_3.cartesian(i, j)) << i << ", " << j;
    }
}

std::mt19937_64 rng(0);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> randReal(0, resolution);
// compare the results of 2D and 3D transformations of random locations
for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(1e4); ++i) {
    Float x(randReal(rng));
    Float y(randReal(rng));
    auto world_2 = transformV2W_2(Point_2(x, y));
    auto world_3 = transformV2W_3(Point_3(x, y, 0));
    EXPECT_EQ(world_2.x(), world_3.x()) << world_2 << ", " << world_3;

    auto voxel_2 = transformW2V_2(world_2);
    auto voxel_3 = transformW2V_3(world_3);
    EXPECT_EQ(voxel_2.x(), voxel_3.x()) << voxel_2 << ", " << voxel_3;

}
}
```

Comment: With double, it is expected that `a*b==a*b` may be false (without involving NaN). That's what you get with an inexact kernel...

Comment: Would this be deterministic for an inexact kernel? i.e.  `a*b==a*b` resolves to false every single time it is evaluated, for two given values of `a` and `b`?